# App crashes when MapKit annotation tapped

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotation, sigabrt

I am developing app to virtualize twitter trends. I fetched the locations of places and create annotation for each of them. Unfortunately when I tap the annotation, the app crashes and gives a sigabrt error on main.m file. In my first run it worked, but after that every time I get the error. I don't know what I changed.

```
   2012-01-15 12:34:29.786 twittertrends[1248:ef03] -[NSCFNumber stringByStandardizingWhitespace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5854b10
    2012-01-15 12:34:29.790 twittertrends[1248:ef03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber stringByStandardizingWhitespace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5854b10'
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x012725a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x013c6313 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x012740bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x011e3966 ___forwarding___ + 966
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x011e3522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
        5   UIKit                               0x005f4340 -[UICalloutView setSubtitle:animated:] + 88
        6   UIKit                               0x005f4010 -[UICalloutView setSubtitle:] + 49
        7   MapKit                              0x003630ac -[MKAnnotationContainerView _showBubbleForAnnotationView:bounce:scrollToFit:userInitiated:avoid:] + 537
        8   MapKit                              0x003643ed -[MKAnnotationContainerView _setSelectedAnnotationView:bounce:pressed:scrollToFit:userInitiated:avoid:] + 653
        9   MapKit                              0x0035d4bc -[MKAnnotationContainerView _setSelectedAnnotationView:bounce:pressed:scrollToFit:userInitiated:] + 144
        10  MapKit                              0x00334ab3 -[MKMapView handleTap:] + 459
        11  UIKit                               0x007554f2 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 730
        12  UIKit                               0x007514fe -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 47
        13  UIKit                               0x00757afc _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 584
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x0125389b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x011e86e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x011b11d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x011b0840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x011b0761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
        19  GraphicsServices                    0x01e501c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
        20  GraphicsServices                    0x01e50289 GSEventRun + 115
        21  UIKit                               0x004d2c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
        22  twittertrends                       0x00002669 main + 121
        23  twittertrends                       0x000025e5 start + 53
    )





#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Mapkit/Mapkit.h"


@interface AvailablePlaces : NSObject <MKAnnotation>{

    NSString *_name;
    NSString *_address;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;

}

@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (copy) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

---

```
#import "AvailablePlaces.h"


@implementation AvailablePlaces
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize address = _address;
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.name = [name copy];
        self.address = [address copy];
        _coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)title {
    return _name;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return _address;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_name release];
    _name = nil;
    [_address release];
    _address = nil;    
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---viewcontroller.m-----

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
        coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;            
        AvailablePlaces *annotation = [[[AvailablePlaces alloc] initWithName:name address:woeid coordinate:coordinate] autorelease];
        [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

-----main.m----------

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: "I don't know what I changed." use version control.

Comment: There should be an error message, most likely and exception (and I guess it's about an unrecognized selector). Please post that.

Comment: search in your project in xcode by string stringByStandardizingWhitespace. somewhere you call it over wrong object. you called it over NSNumber class and there is no such method in such class.

Comment: i searched but found nothing.

Comment: Can you show me code of viewforannotation delegate method?

Comment: @ValeriyVan: Look at the stack trace. `stringByStandardizingWhitespace` is not called by uyqusuz's code, it's called by `-[UICalloutView setSubtitle:animated:]` (that is: Apple calls it).

Comment: @Armaan I don't have viewforanotation delegate method

Comment: @uyqusuz I have the same problem... Have you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you pass an instance of `NSNumber` as `name` in your call to `initWithName:address:coordinate:`. So you need to pay attention that your `name` variable contains an `NSString` instead.

Comment: i can't understand what you mean "Most likely you pass an instance of NSNumber as name". name is defined as nsstring and I can put annotation on the map view but when I tap on the annotation get the error. can you be more specific about what should I change on code.

Comment: You have *defined* it to be an NSString, but it seems that the crash is because you did pass a NSNumber instead. You can easily verify this by adding a log message to `- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate`: `NSLog(@"Name is \"%@\" (class %@)", name, [name class]);`

Comment: Yes. DarkDust is correct I have tested my self. If you will pass NSNumber in subtitle application will give you exactly above described crash log.

Comment: @uyqusuz: Is it also a NSCFString when it's crashing?

Comment: program views annotations on the map there is no problem with that but when I tap the annotation program crash. which method handles clicking on annotation?

Comment: Put debug point on subtitle method or write down nslog inside getter of subtitle.

Comment: when you click on annotation it will first collect property like title and subtitle to display it on call out. So, add log or debug inside of subtitle method of annotation

Comment: thanks a lot I don't understand why but subtitle has string value but contains numbers.